# Repeat a transpose formula that returns an array every n rows, but increment the formula by one row only

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Context: I need to import this in a tool that only accepts a specific format. My table contains rows for invoices and columns for the products in the invoice.
Products 1 and 2 come in from my export - Product 3 in the example is a copy of Product 2 and is required as a line item in the invoice.

--> I need to transpose each Invoice row (3 columns into 3 rows), and when pulling down the formula I want to increment it by 1 row only, so as to move to the next array of 3 transposed rows. Repeat n times for n invoice rows.

I've tried using transpose functions and think this could be solved with an array formula but am not familiar enough with them to find a solution. I've colour-coded the expected result in the screenshot below.

Thank you!

[image: Screenshot of input+output expected result]

Comment: Have you looked into power query? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098

Comment: Excel is not Google Sheets. Which of the two are you actually using? Please only use appropriate tags.

Comment: I am using Google Sheets but am aware that a lot of the functions are shared.

@P.b I haven't. I will check out the link, thank you.

Comment: That's Microsoft only. Please untag Excel. A lot of the functions appear the same, but a lot don't - at all. Untagged Excel and Excel-formula.

Comment: Will your data always have the same number of products and invoices? As in there will always be 3 of each.

Comment: @KevinP.
It will always have 3 products, but the number of invoices can change. 
I've had some success with `FLATTEN()` but I realise it's probably not a very robust solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=arrayformula({"Invoice","Product","Amount payable";
split(flatten(A4:A5&"❄️"&regexreplace(B3:D3,"\s-.*",)&"❄️"&B4:D5),"❄️")})
```

[image]

Learn more about this technique: [Unpivot In Google Sheets With Formulas](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/unpivot-in-google-sheets/)